# How to set up a wireguard VPN tunnel programmatically (in C)?

Tags: c, networking, interface, vpn, wireguard

I'm trying to set up a new  wireguard client and create a new VPN tunnel with the server (10.6.0.1) programmatically by using this single file C library https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/tree/contrib/embeddable-wg-library wirguard.h. Following is my code. However it seems that the tunnel is not properly established.

```
#include <libmnl/libmnl.h>
#include "/home/WG/wireguard.h"

#define SERVER_IP "10.6.0.1"
#define ENDPOINT_IP "192.168.30.209"
#define SERVER_PORT 51820
#define CLIENT_PRIVATE_KEY "private_key_goes_here"
#define CLIENT_PUBLIC_KEY "  public  key goes here  "
#define SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY  "  public  key goes here  "
#define CLIENT_IP "10.6.0.2"  /* Client-side IP address for the WireGuard tunnel*/
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1036

int main() {

    wg_peer new_peer = {
        .flags = WGPEER_HAS_PUBLIC_KEY | WGPEER_REPLACE_ALLOWEDIPS
    };
    wg_device new_device = {
        .name = "wg",
        .listen_port = 51820,
        .flags = WGDEVICE_HAS_PRIVATE_KEY | WGDEVICE_HAS_LISTEN_PORT,
        .first_peer = &new_peer,
        .last_peer = &new_peer

    };
      // Convert base64 strings to binary keys using wg_key_from_base64
    wg_key private_key;
    wg_key public_key;
    wg_key server_public_key;

    if (wg_key_from_base64(private_key, CLIENT_PRIVATE_KEY) < 0) {
        perror("Invalid private key");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (wg_key_from_base64(public_key, CLIENT_PUBLIC_KEY) < 0) {
        perror("Invalid public key");
        exit(1);
    }

     if (wg_key_from_base64(server_public_key, SERVER_PUBLIC_KEY) < 0) {
        perror("Invalid server public key");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Set the public key of the server
    memcpy(new_peer.public_key, server_public_key, sizeof(wg_key));

    // Set the endpoint address and port of the server
    new_peer.endpoint.addr.sa_family = AF_INET;
    if (inet_aton(ENDPOINT_IP, &new_peer.endpoint.addr4.sin_addr) == 0) {
        perror("Invalid server IP address");
        return 1;
    }
    new_peer.endpoint.addr4.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);  
    if (wg_add_device(new_device.name) < 0) {
        perror("Unable to add device");
        exit(1);
    }

  if (wg_set_device(&new_device) < 0) {
    perror("Unable to set device");
        exit(1);
    }

   sleep(3);


  Free the allocated memory before exiting
   free(new_device->name);
   free(new_device);
   free(peer);

return 0;
}
```

This is the output for: **sudo wg**

interface: wg
listening port: 51820

peer:
endpoint: 192.168.30.209:51820
allowed ips: (none)

In wireshark, it lists down the wg interface somewhere in the bottom. When I try to select and listen to the port, it says the “wg device is not up”. for ifconfig its not showing the wg interface.
Any mistakes I have made ? I think it’s because the CLIENT_IP address has not been applied properly. I’m struggling with this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Tip: Absolute paths in includes are sketchy. Best to use `#include <wireguard.h>`, and using `-I /home/WG` to tell the compiler where to look for includes.

Comment: Thank you very much. Any suggestion about other mistakes?

Comment: No idea. I did spend a fair amount time looking at yesterday, but I didn't see anything. Without docs, and without familiarity with Wireguard, that doesn't mean all that much.